# Checkbox accessibility showing no relation

Tags: html, checkbox, accessibility, antd, uiaccessibility

I have a group of checkbox with one heading. while checking the accessibility i am getting error "All elements with the name "recognitionOption" do not reference the same element with aria-labelledby" and "Fieldset contains unrelated inputs".

```
<fieldset>
   <legend id="item-box">Item Box</legend>
   <div>Choose your favourite item</div>
   <div aria-labelledby="item-box">
      <div class="ant-row ant-form-item">
         <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control-wrapper">
            <div class="ant-form-item-control">
               <span class="ant-form-item-children">
                  <div>
                     <label><span class="ant-radio ant-radio-checked"><input name="itemOption" id="itemOption1" type="radio" class="ant-radio-input" aria-label="item1" value="10" checked=""><span class="ant-radio-inner"></span></span></label><span class="small-box">Jackfruit</span>
                  </div>
                  <div><label class="ant-radio-wrapper"><span class="ant-radio"><input name="itemOption" id="itemOption2" type="radio" class="ant-radio-input" aria-label="item2" value="20"><span class="ant-radio-inner"></span></span></label><span>Mango</span></div>
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

It would be helpful if someone can give some suggestion on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) in details for `aria-labelledby` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use in your case **aria** tags

You need to read [Labeling Controls](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/)

You need to follow these steps:

1. Remove aria tags
2. Set the text inside the labels (In your case, move a span with text to label)
3. Associate inputs with labels

Your correct html:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend id="item-box">Item Box</legend>
  <div>Choose your favourite item</div>
  <div class="ant-row ant-form-item">
    <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control-wrapper">
      <div class="ant-form-item-control">
        <span class="ant-form-item-children">
          <div>
            <label for="itemOption1">
              <span class="ant-radio ant-radio-checked">
                <input name="itemOption" id="itemOption1" type="radio" class="ant-radio-input" value="10" checked>
                <span class="ant-radio-inner"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="small-box">Jackfruit</span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label class="ant-radio-wrapper" for="itemOption2">
              <span class="ant-radio">
                <input name="itemOption" id="itemOption2" type="radio" class="ant-radio-input" value="20">
                <span class="ant-radio-inner"></span>
              </span>
              <span>Mango</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```